# Screen freezes after login when using a Broadcom BCM4311

Tags: 11.04, wireless, dual-boot, login, freeze

After using airmon-ng and disabling eth0 and wlan0, and restarting my computer in dual boot mode under Ubuntu 11.04 my computer froze right after logging into Ubuntu. I tried re-enabling eth0 and wlan0, but i'm not sure if it was done properly.

When I plug an Ethernet cable into my computer it starts up with no problems, no freezing, no nothing. However, when I unplug the cable the computer freezes shortly after. I figure that this issue may revolve around a wireless related process? If this isn't solved could I reinstall Ubuntu 11.04 in dual boot without having to worry about the 20GB of partitioned space that I allocated it?

- I'm using Broadcom BCM4311 hardware, and I have not mounted any network file systems.

Comment: What kind of (wireless) hardware do you use? Do you mount any network file systems?

Comment: I'm using Broadcom BCM4311 hardware, and I have not mounted any network file systems.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).